# Jquery: filter input on keypress

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, keypress, keyup

I have a text field, which will accept only the following characters:

**Allowed characters: [a-z 0-9 + # - .]**

This is the same filter *SO* does in the 'Tags' field, when you're asking a question.
If the user types an invalid character, i want the current text field value to remain unchanged. I tried:

```
$('#post_tags').keypress(function(event){
    var char = String.fromCharCode(event.which)
    var txt = $(this).val()

    if (! txt.match(/[^A-Za-z0-9+#-\.]/)){
        $(this).val(txt.replace(char, ''));
    }
})
```

Why it doesn't work? Thanks!

Comment: How does it not work? What does it do instead of the behaviour you want?

Comment: What about `DEL` `BACKSPACE` and the arrow keys?!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
/[^A-Za-z0-9+#-\.]/
```

This negates the match of any one of those characters. To make it match more than one character, you have to use a `+` in there:

```
/[^A-Za-z0-9+#-\.]+/
                  ^
```

And now to match the whole string, you need to add anchors:

```
/^[^A-Za-z0-9+#-\.]+$/
 ^                  ^
```

EDIT: Okay, it seems that the `-` here is also creating a range from character `#` to `.`. In this case, you can either escape it, or put it at the end:

```
/^[^A-Za-z0-9+#\-\.]+$/

/^[^A-Za-z0-9+#\.-]+$/
```

Comment: if you return false in the handler it will prevent the value to be updated

Comment: @Fernando Use anchors if that's the case, `^` meaning the beginning of a string and `$` meaning the end of a string. This ensures that the whole strings matches (or not) the pattern.

Comment: @Fernando I didn't notice the `-` character being naughty here ;) See the edit to my answer.

Comment: @Fernando Also, why don't you use `if (txt.match(/^[A-Za-z0-9+#\.-]+$/))` instead of using double negations?

Answer (score 14):

This worked for me:

```js
$(function(){
    $('#t').keypress(function(e){
        var txt = String.fromCharCode(e.which);
        console.log(txt + ' : ' + e.which);
        if(!txt.match(/[A-Za-z0-9+#.]/)) 
        {
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="t" />
```

Comment: It is possible to insert text into input from clipboard. Also DEL and BACKSPACE do not work.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to replace the char, only prevent it.

```
var char = String.fromCharCode(event.which)
if (!char.match(/^[^A-Za-z0-9+#\.\-]+$/)) event.preventDefault();
```

Comment: This works instead: 
`if (!char.match(/[A-Za-z0-9+#\.\-]/)) event.preventDefault();`

Answer (score 1):

### Alternate Solution

One thing that might help would be to use the `.which` field instead. Then simply return false when it doesn't fit. I actually have a [***huge object***](http://jsfiddle.net/SpYk3/NePCm/) full of .which info for all major browsers. It includes arrays you could borrow from it to create something like:

```
var alphaNumericNcontrols = [ 8,9,13,16,17,18,19,20,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,44,45,46,145,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,96,97,98,99,100,101,102,103,104,105 ],
    illegal = {
        reg: [ 106,111,191,220 ],
        shift: [ 56,59,188,190,191,220,222 ]
    }

$(document).on("keydown", "input[type=text]", function(e) {
    var eKey = e.which || e.keyCode;
    if (alphaNumericNcontrols.indexOf(eKey) === -1) return false;
    if (illegal.reg.indexOf(eKey) > -1) return false;
    if (e.shiftKey && illegal.shift.indexOf(eKey) > -1) return false;
});
```

## See Working Example Here

Keep in mind my Object is not perfect and there are some updates I probably need to make to it, but i did my best to establish everything from every possible major browser!

Comment: I really like this solution and it's perfect for what I need. Do you know how I can prevent someone from adding emoji? Right now it still lets me do that.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone.

Actually my problem was a little more difficult: filter invalid keys and start a ajax call for valid ones, in 2 different ways: if the user press SPACE/COMMA or while he/her still typing. Here's the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#post_tags').keypress(function(e){
    var txt = String.fromCharCode(e.which);
    console.log(txt + ' : ' + e.which);

    if(txt.match(/^[^A-Za-z0-9+#\-\.]+$/))
    {
          return false;
    }
})

$('#post_tags').keyup(function(event){
      code = event.which
      var token = String.fromCharCode(code)
      var txt = $(this).val()

              //create a new tag, take it out of textfield
      if (code == 32 || code == 188)
      {
        console.log("AJAX new word keyup")

          $.ajax({
            type: 'get',
            url: '/posts/tags_change',
            dataType: "json",
            data: "query=" + $(this).val(),

            success: function(data) {
            console.log(data)
            $('#post_tags').val('')
            },

            error: function(data) {
                alert("Ajax error")
            }
          });
    }
    else
    {
                    //do autocomplete ajax
        console.log("typing:" + txt)
    }

});
```

})

Dont' know if this is 100% right!