# Restrict AltGr Special Charackters

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having a bit of a problem here. I'm using a JavaScript Library to filter inputs for a inputField. It works fine so far, only the allowed charackters are entered.
But if the User presses AltGr (right alt || CTRL+ALT) he is still able to enter special charackters like @,€,[ and so on.
Is there any way to restrict this? I tried the event.preventDefault(); way on doing this with keydown(); but it didn't work...

Here's the tiny snippet I'm using for my input filter:

```
$(".field").filter_input({ regex: '[a-zA-Z0-9]' });
```

This is the link to the jQ-Plugin I'm using:
http://www.thimbleopensource.com/tutorials-snippets/jquery-plugin-filter-text-input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line 37 of the library (http://www.thimbleopensource.com/download/jquery/jquery.filter_input.js) returns and doesn't do any filtering if you're pressing CTRL or ALT.

```
if (event.ctrlKey || event.altKey) return;
```

Your options are:

1. Try the solution @Sukanya posted (this doesn't exactly do what you're looking for I don't think) and/or write your own. See for hints: [Jquery: filter input on keypress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17220667/jquery-filter-input-on-keypress)
2. Pick a different library
3. Download a copy of the library and delete line 37

Comment: Deleted Line 37, now it's working just fine. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<input id="txt" type="text" />

<script>
$("input:text").blur(function () {
                checkSpecialChar();
            });
            function checkSpecialChar()
            {
                var checkString = $("#txt").val();                
                if (checkString != "") {
                    if (/[^A-Za-z\d]/.test(checkString)) {
                        alert("Please enter only letter and numeric characters");                        
                        return (false);
                    }
                }
            }
</script>
```