# PrimeFaces selectOneMenu with custom editable inputField

Tags: jsf, primefaces, selectonemenu

Silly question, but that's my situation. I am having editable PrimeFaces `selectOneMenu` where `inputField` has following restriction:

- lower and upper limit of number typed in
- predefined text allowed
- when decimal number is being typed allow only 2 decimal numbers

All is good except the last one with decimal number restriction. What it means is that I can't type there `1.111` but only `1.11`. Change event `keyUp` for `selectOneMenu` is sadly added to the tag select but not to input.

Any ideas how to solve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This calls for a custom validator. Create one which checks for the predefined values, if no match is found, check the number format. Basic example:

```
@FacesValidator("myValidator")
public class MyValidator implements Validator
{

  private List<String> predefinedValues = Arrays.asList("my", "list");

  @Override
  public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value)
  throws ValidatorException
  {
    String valueStr = (String) value;
    // Check if value is predefined
    if (predefinedValues.contains(valueStr)) {
      return;
    }
    // If not predefined, check number format
    if (! valueStr.matches("^\\d+(\\.\\d\\d?)?$")) {
      throw new ValidatorException(new FacesMessage("Value is invalid!"));
    }
    // Check number limits...
  }

}
```

The validator can be used in your XHTML as:

```
<p:selectOneMenu editable="true" ...>
  ...
  <f:validator validatorId="myValidator" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

As an alternative you could use jQuery to find the input field and bind a `keypress` listener to it. See for example: [Jquery: filter input on keypress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17220667/jquery-filter-input-on-keypress). However, I would keep the validator in place. Users could paste text for example.

See also:

- [How to perform validation in JSF, how to create a custom validator in JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6047866/how-to-perform-validation-in-jsf-how-to-create-a-custom-validator-in-jsf)
- [Regular expression for floating point numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12643009/regular-expression-for-floating-point-numbers)

Comment: Thank you, but its not what I want. I already have validator. What I would like to achieve is that it is not even possible to type in. Something like inputmask.

Comment: I've added that as an alternative to the answer.

Comment: Ah... that makes sense. :)